# JavaFX set appearance of non-editable text field in css

Tags: java, css, javafx

Is it possible to set the appearance of non-editable text fields in css? I want non-editable text fields to look like labels. I couldn't find any answers to this (or similar) question, I tried this:

```
.text-input:editable {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

But that didn't work, obviously.

Comment: You might find the answer to this related question interesting: [How do I create an editable Label in javafx 2.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572398/how-do-i-create-an-editable-label-in-javafx-2-2).  That question has more requirements than simple styling so the answer is more complicated than what you need.

Answer (score 6):

```
.text-input:readonly {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
```

Should've checked [JavaFX CSS reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) before asking a question!