# TextBox tool for drawing application - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create some drawing functionality, effectively very similar to MSPaint. I want to make a `TextBox` tool, such that I can draw a textbox on my canvas and have a user type in it like a real textbox. Once the user clicks off of the textbox or presses escape, then I would `"stroke"` the text to the `GraphicsContext`.

I'm not sure how to do this. My current attempt has me using `StackPane` to stack two canvases on top of each other. I let the user `"draw"` a textbox with the mouse, and then I create a textbox programmatically which I am trying to pass the `keyevents` into. Then when the user clicks off, I write `textbox.getText()` to the `GraphicsContext`. This has not been very successful. Specifically, I'm not sure how to handle special keys like `BACKSPACE` and `DELETE` and letting the user click to place the cursor.

I'm looking for advice on a better approach.

Comment: This is probably a comment that's a bit of a pain (I remember asking for directions once and being told "Well, I wouldn't start from here") - maybe a canvas isn't the best approach for this. If you're not too far into the project, perhaps using a `Pane` and adding nodes to it (`Shape` subclasses, `Text` for your text, etc) would be easier. But of course you may have other good reasons to use a canvas.

Comment: I effectively want to recreate MS Paint, with a few additional features. I also want the ability to easily turn the '"canvas"' (or whatever it is) into something I can send over a socket. I'm worried about things like the "Paint Bucket", and how I would implement that with the 'Pane' solution.

Comment: "Paint bucket" would be quite hard either way, I think... not sure. If transmitting it as image data is acceptable, you can [`snapshot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot-javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters-javafx.scene.image.WritableImage-) any node to create a JavaFX image, [convert](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html#fromFXImage-javafx.scene.image.Image-java.awt.image.BufferedImage-) to a `BufferedImage` and use [`ImageIO`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) to send it.

Comment: I'd rather save it was a set of commands and send that. I need to be able to synchronize this over the network (so just sending an image isn't good enough if it's a Pane) and it would also need to facilitate undo and redo. I got the "Paint Bucket" working using a Flood Fill algorithm after calling snapshot on the canvas, but I have no idea how I would implement that on something which is not an image.

Comment: This is a pretty wide open question, so it is hard to answer, especially when the additional desires in the comment section are taken into account.  Perhaps a StackPane, with the canvas on the bottom and a dynamic editing section on top, in which you could place some [editable text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572398/how-do-i-create-an-editable-label-in-javafx-2-2) and when [onAction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextField.html#onActionProperty) is fired remove the textfield and stroke the text on to the canvas.

Comment: Just use a `TextField` / `TextArea` and remove the background/border.