# JavaFX Possible to write "Borderless" in a 2d Shape?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to copy a symbol form an old java swing Application. This is the Old one:

[image]

And this is my attempt to copy this symbol: 
[image]

beside that the two ellipses are not in the same dimension - If the Mouse isn't over the Textfield I want them to be displayed as Label but as soon as the mouse hovers about  the Textfield it should show up.

Anyone any ideas how to implement ? Is there a css-style for something like this ?

My ( temporary ) solution looks like this:

```
public class CustomTextField {
    private Group group;

    private Label label;
    private TextField textField;

    public StdeTextField(String text){
        label = new Label(text);
        label.relocate(5,2.5);
        textField = new TextField(text);

        label.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
            group.getChildren().remove(label);
            group.getChildren().add(textField);

            textField.setText(label.getText());
        });

        textField.setOnMouseExited(event -> {
            group.getChildren().remove(textField);
            group.getChildren().add(label);

            label.setText(textField.getText());
        });

        group = new Group();
        group.getChildren().addAll(label);
    }

    public Group getGroup() {
        return group;
    }
}
```

The Label and the Text field has a offset, because I can't figure out how to get the Size of an Node if it's not rendered.

Comment: CSS alone won’t cover it.  While you can use a hover selector to make the TextField appear, you certainly don’t want it to disappear when the mouse is moved away from it.  You probably want it to revert to a Label only when the user presses Enter or Esc, or clicks somewhere else… like an editable Cell in a tree, table, or list.

Comment: yes this is exact what I want! A hover selector can cover it ? I'll learn how to use it.

Comment: I made a point of saying that a hover selector will not do the job properly.

Comment: Related question: [How do I create an editable Label in javafx 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25572398/how-do-i-create-an-editable-label-in-javafx-2-2).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could achieve this without having to replace the node using CSS only. There is one difference though: The text is still moved/clipped as in a fully visible `TextField`:

```
group.getStyleClass().add("custom-text-field");
...
scene.getStylesheets().add("/my/stylesheet/location.css");
```

Unfortunately since `:not()` is not available in javafx, we have to copy the default look over from modena.css. This allows us to hide the `TextField`'s decorations for `TextField`, unless the group is hovered or the `TextField` pressed (changing selection).

**Stylesheet**

```css
/* "default" style when hovered/pressed */
.custom-text-field>.text-field:hover,
.custom-text-field>.text-field:pressed {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-text-box-border, -10%), -fx-text-box-border),
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);

    -fx-highlight-fill: dodgerblue;      
    -fx-highlight-text-fill: white;
    -fx-display-caret: true;
}

.custom-text-field>.text-field:hover:focused,
.custom-text-field>.text-field:pressed:focused {
    -fx-background-color:
        -fx-focus-color,
        -fx-control-inner-background,
        -fx-faint-focus-color,
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);

    -fx-highlight-fill: dodgerblue;      
    -fx-highlight-text-fill: white;
    -fx-display-caret: true;
}

/* Hide everything but text when neither hovered nor pressed */
.custom-text-field>.text-field,
.custom-text-field>.text-field:focused {
    -fx-background-color:
        null, null, null, null;
    -fx-highlight-fill: null;    
    -fx-highlight-text-fill: black;
    -fx-display-caret: false;
}
.custom-text-field:hover>.text-field:focused,
.custom-text-field>.text-field:pressed:focused {
    -fx-background-color:
        -fx-focus-color,
        -fx-control-inner-background,
        -fx-faint-focus-color,
        linear-gradient(from 0px 0px to 0px 5px, derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -9%), -fx-control-inner-background);

    -fx-highlight-fill: dodgerblue;      
    -fx-highlight-text-fill: white;
    -fx-display-caret: true;
}

.custom-text-field>.text-field,
.custom-text-field>.text-field:focused {
    -fx-background-color:
        null, null, null, null;
    -fx-highlight-fill: null;    
    -fx-highlight-text-fill: black;
    -fx-display-caret: false;
}
```

---

If you want to go with your initial approach, you could simply make the `TextField` invisible, instead of changing the contents of the group. This way layout is still done for it; it's just not rendered. Furthermore a binding could be used to synchronize text and visiblity:

```
label.textProperty().bind(textField.textProperty());
label.visibleProperty().bind(textField.visibleProperty().not());

// replace listeners with bindings to hover/pressed
textField.visibleProperty().bind(textField.hoverProperty().or(textField.pressedProperty()));
```

Comment: I get some errors with this cssfile. Everytime the Method 'derive' is called. The error Message is: Mismatched parameters `([[from <point> to <point> | to <side-or-corner>] ,]? [[repeat | reflect] ,]? <color-stop> [, <color-stop>]+)`. Do you know how to fix them ? - It compiles but the TextField doesn't change appearance.

Comment: My Bad! I added the styleclass to the Textfield not to the textfield's group!